# Scheme - predicate gets null

Tags: lambda, scheme, predicate

I just build a scheme code that uses predicate and iterate over a list.

this is the code:

```
(define (filter para lst)
       (foldr (lambda (x y) 
                (if (para x) 
                    (cons x y) y)) '() lst))
```

for example `(filter odd? '(1 2 3))` will return `'(1 3)`

The lamda gets in the start `'()` and 3 - and make `(para x)` which is `(odd? '())` and it works.

But if I write `(odd? '())` it will print an error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter, `x`, is the current element of the list. The second one, `y`, is the accumulator. So on the first invocation `x` is 3 and `y` is `'()`. So you're not doing `(odd? '())` and `(cons '() 3)`, you're doing `(odd? 3)` and `(cons 3 '())`.

Comment: You're right!.. I just tried to swap and make (para y) instead and it gave me an error...Thanks!